# Is it ok to explain the justification for a question in the question itself (or comment)?

Tags: discussion, comments, off-topic

If a poster has a question that is clearly on-topic according to the help, but is drawing comments that it is "off topic", should the justification for the question (such as citing the relevant line in the help) be put in the question itself to make it more visible, or just bury it in the comments?

The reason for asking this is that some readers may not read through all the comments and see the justification and thereby just repeat the mistake of earlier readers.

Comment: Well, I don't think we should consider this a justification, but a necessary part of the question to make that question more clear (and on-topic). It is like explaining why another question isn't a valid duplicate. So yes, please write that into the question.

Answer (score 6):

If a question isn't clear enough that users are confused, *then clarify the question*.  If the question itself is about as clear as you can make it, then let it stand and see where the votes lie.  Arguing about a question's validity belongs in Meta, not in the question body; it detracts from the question by including irrelevant information.  It's noise.

Look at it from a long perspective; if you come back to this question in a year or more, how does this look?  Nobody's going to care that you were arguing about the question; they're just looking for the information that led them to click on it in the first place.

In the heat of the moment, yeah, people want to defend their question, because they want it to be answered.  It's understandable.  But when trying to build a high quality repository of knowledge, it doesn't belong.  It's ephemeral noise, and putting it in the question itself preserves it for way longer than it should be.